# How do I get back emacs on Mac Lion?

Tags: emacs

I have Mac Lion, I was trying to install Emacs 23.3 using [these instructions](http://www.dansanderson.com/blog/2009/01/installing-emacs-23-on-mac-os.html) and others.

Emacs 23 didn't work, and I lost the one that was already there (emacs 2. something). Now, when I type: emacs in the terminal, I get: -bash: Emacs: command not found.

Can anyone instruct me how to get it back?

Comment: Are you sure is says `Emacs: command not found`? Try `emacs` in lower-case; commands in the terminal are case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes, and I tried typing it in lower-case and I got: -bash: emacs: command not found

Answer (score 2):

[Another Emacs distribution for Mac](http://emacsformacosx.com/) that works fine under Lion. This is not for running in the terminal though.

Comment: Thanks indeed for this. I hope I could fix my emacs issue though.

Comment: The standard Cocoa emacs build works fine in a terminal. You can invoke it as: `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw`.

Comment: So, I guess that adding `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/` to PATH would do the trick? PATH probably doesn't contain a path inside the Emacs.app package.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the included copy of emacs is in `/usr/bin` so typing `/usr/bin/emacs` in Terminal should invoke it for you.

That directory should be in your path though, so you may have problems unrelated to emacs.  If you `echo $PATH` does it display reasonable output?

Comment: $ cd /usr/bin/emacs
-bash: cd: /usr/bin/emacs: No such file or directory

Comment: Hrm, it sounds like you lost emacs.

Comment: Yeah :/ I hate it anyways :p Gonna use Aquamacs instead.